# Revoking a Github app's authorization 404 not found error

Tags: validation, github, access-token, github-api

I'm looking to access an endpoint that lets me revoke my Github app's authorization. I'm quite confused on the issue, because.

1. There are 3 different endpoints, none of which seem to be listed in the valid endpoints when you access api.github.com:

- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/oauth-applications?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-an-app-token
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/oauth-applications?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-an-app-authorization
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/installations?apiVersion=2022-11-28#revoke-an-installation-access-token

2. I've tried using all 3 of them, but all of them gave me `404` errors.
3. In 2 of the endpoints listed above, it says that:

> You must use Basic Authentication when accessing this endpoint, using the application's client_id and client_secret as the username and password.

However, none of the example codes for them include `client_secret`, always just `client_id`.

I'm using RestAPI to do my calls. Here's my code:

```
        chrome.storage.local.get(["github_token"]).then((result) => {
            let token = result.github_token;
            if (token) {
                let client_id = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID
                const URL = `https://api.github.com/applications/${client_id}/grant`;    
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 204) {
                        console.log("logged out")
                        navigate('/auth')
                    } else {
                        console.log("awww fuck")
                    }
                }
                });
                xhr.open('DELETE', URL, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `token ${token}`);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.github.v3+json');
                xhr.send();
            } else {
                // smth went wrong
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue in a NODE.js API, after doing some research and testing, I found the way sending `client_id` and `client_secret` as basic authentication in the header instead of Bearer with `access_token`, and the `access_token` as data in the delete request.

I can provide a code snippet in JavaScript using Axios that might help:

```
const revokeAccess = await axios.delete(
  `https://api.github.com/applications/${CLIENT_ID_GITHUB}/grant`,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID_GITHUB + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET_GITHUB).toString('base64')}`,
      Accept: 'application/vnd.github+json',
      'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
    },
    data: {
      access_token: access_token,
    }
  }
);
```

Give this a try, and let me know if it helps resolve your issue!

Comment: thanks, that worked!!! did you also work with updating the contents of a repo? ie commit/push?